# How to insert the .env into a folder and run the nodemon?

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables

**SERVER.JS RESUME DOTENV**

```
const dotenv   = require('dotenv-safe');
this.dotenv   = dotenv.load();
```

**Problems:**

**1)** I can not run the nodemon if it has only the .env file, it runs only if it contains the .env and .env.example files and I would like to know why and how to correctly match it.

**2)** How to insert the `.env` in the `/env` **folder** without **the problem nodemon?**

**3)** In my start script of `package.json` is the following `"start_dev": "nodemon app/backend/src/start.js"`, however it is giving the **following error:**

```
nodemon app / backend / src / start.js
[nodemon] 1.18.9
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *. *
[nodemon] starting `node app / backend / src / start.js`
consign v0.1.6 Initialized in C: \ Users \ THIAGOSAAD \ Documents \ DEVELOPMENT \ NEORIS \ ALIANSCE \ aliansce-app-analyticals-panel
fs.js: 115
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env.example'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js: 436: 3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js: 341: 35)
    C: \ Users \ THIAGOSAAD \ Documents \ DEVELOPMENT \ NEORIS \ ALIANSCE \ aliansce-app-analyticals-panel \ node_modules \ dotenv-safe \ index.js: 27: 45)
    at new Application (C: \ Users \ THIAGOSAAD \ Documents \ DEVELOPMENT \ NEORIS \ ALIANSCE \ aliansce-app-analyticals-panel \ app \ backend \ src \ config \ server.js: 11: 32)
    at-the-object. <anonymous> (C: \ Users \ THIAGOSAAD \ Documents \ DEVELOPMENT \ NEORIS \ ALIANSCE \ aliansce-app-analyticals-panel \ app \ backend \ src \ config \ server.js: 65: 18)
    at Module._compile (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 688: 30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 699: 10)
    at Module.load (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 598: 32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 537: 12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 529: 3)
    at Module.require (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 636: 17)
    at require (internal / modules / cjs / helpers.js: 20: 18)
    at aliasce-app-analyticals-panel \ app \ backend \ src \ start.js: 1: 78)
    at Module._compile (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 688: 30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 699: 10)
    at Module.load (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 598: 32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting ...
```

**And if I run the nodemon in the `C:\Users\username\Documents\DEVELOPMENT\NEORIS\ ALIANSCE\aliansce-app-analyticals-panel\app\ ackend\src directory`
It works!**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at this line of code - https://github.com/rolodato/dotenv-safe/blob/master/index.js#L27

It tries to read file `.env.example` but can not find it in the current folder (run `pwd` to check it)

It might be 3 ways to solve issue

1) Run

```
cd app/backend/src
nodemon start.js
```

2) Move files `.env`, `.env.example` to parent folder (`aliansce-app-analyticals-panel`) and then run `nodemon app/backend/src/start.js`

3) Do not use `dotenv-safe` at all. Use your own simple script like this one

Just look at this simple example:

- https://github.com/olegdovger/pizza-delivery-api/blob/master/lib/env.js (script)
- https://github.com/olegdovger/pizza-delivery-api/blob/master/index.js#L1 (how to invoke script)

Comment: Thanks @OlegDovger, when running nodemon in the directory ../src it runs correctly, however when running the nodemon in the main directory where the package.json is from the error and can not access the process.env why does this happen?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this Oleg! I have managed to use your code to workaround this - example below.

Answer (score 0):

With help of @[OlegDover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593758/olegdovger) and [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs), I managed to pass `.env` file from a different path and use nodemon for hot-reloading during development.

e.g. `$ nodemon --watch /path/to/.env server.js --envPath=path/to/.env` will pick up changes to .env file and restart deployment.

### Example Code

**`.env`**

```
EXAMPLE_HOST=myhost
EXAMPLE_PORT=5566
```

**`env.js`**

```
/*
 * Module dependencies
 */

const fs = require("fs");
const yargs = require("yargs");

/*
 * Custom class to update process.env from custom filepath
 * Ref: https://github.com/olegdovger/pizza-delivery-api/blob/master/lib/env.js
 */

class Env {
  constructor(envPath) {
    this.variables = [];
    this._setup(envPath);
  }

  _setup(envPath) {
    try {
      const data = fs.readFileSync(envPath, {
        encoding: "utf-8",
      });
      const stringArray = data.split("\n");
      this.variables = stringArray.map((string) => {
        const arr = string.split("=");
        return {
          name: arr[0],
          value: arr[1],
        };
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Unable to load .env;", err);
    }
  }

  load() {
    this.variables.forEach((variable) => {
      process.env[variable.name] = variable.value;
    });
  }
}

/*
 * Load .env from argv filepath
 */
const argv = yargs.argv;
new Env(argv["envPath"]).load();

/**
 * Register
 */
module.exports = {
  EXAMPLE_HOST: process.env.EXAMPLE_HOST || "localhost",
  EXAMPLE_PORT: Number(process.env.EXAMPLE_PORT) || 12345,
};
```

**`server.js`**

```
const { EXAMPLE_HOST, EXAMPLE_PORT } = require("./env");
```

The environment variables can then be loaded/used in the project, having the fallback values if they are not defined in the `.env` file.

i.e. if `EXAMPLE_HOST` is not present in `.env`, this value will default to `localhost`